# Android ScrollView scrolls to top after calling setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) on child view

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, visibility

I have a `ScrollView` with a `RelativeLayout` inside it. This `RelativeLayout` then has several `View`s inside it. One of these several `View`s is a `CheckBox`. When the `CheckBox` is checked/unchecked, some of the other `View`s should appear/disappear accordingly.The appearing and disappear is working fine, but every time the target `View`s appear or disappear, the `ScrollView` scrolls all the way to the top and I'm forced to scroll down to see what happened.

The code I use to control visibility is:

```
public void crossCountryCheckboxClicked(View view)
{
    CheckBox crossCountryCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_cross_country);
    EditText crossCountryHoursTextBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cross_country_hours);
    if (crossCountryCheckBox.isChecked())
    {
        crossCountryHoursTextBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        crossCountryHoursTextBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

and the `crossCountryCheckboxClicked()` method is called by specifying the `android:onClick` attribute on the `CheckBox` element in the XML layout file.

Here is the XML layout file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/logbook.app.activities"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flight_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/aeroplane_type"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/flight_date"
        android:hint="@string/aeroplane_type" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/aeroplane_registration"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/aeroplane_type"
        android:hint="@string/aeroplane_registration" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pilot_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/aeroplane_registration"
        android:hint="@string/pilot_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/copilot_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pilot_name"
        android:hint="@string/copilot_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/from_aerodome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/copilot_name"
        android:hint="@string/from_aerodome" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to_aerodome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/copilot_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/from_aerodome"
        android:hint="@string/to_aerodome" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/remarks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/from_aerodome"
        android:hint="@string/remarks" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/aircraft_engine_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/remarks" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/time_of_day_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/aircraft_engine_type_spinner" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/pilot_role_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/time_of_day_spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/on_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pilot_role_spinner"
        android:hint="@string/on_time_hint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/takeoff_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/on_time"
        android:hint="@string/takeoff_time_hint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/landing_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/takeoff_time"
        android:hint="@string/landing_time_hint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/off_time"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/landing_time"
        android:hint="@string/off_time_hint" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/off_time"
        android:onClick="recordTime"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_record" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/off_time"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_record"
        android:onClick="resetAllTimes"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_reset" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_ifr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_record"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_ifr"
        android:onClick="ifrCheckboxClicked" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_cross_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_record"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkbox_ifr"
        android:text="@string/checkbox_cross_country"
        android:onClick="crossCountryCheckboxClicked" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/ifr_type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkbox_ifr"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_ifr_approaches"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ifr_type_spinner"
        android:hint="@string/ifr_landings_label"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <logbook.app.custom.widgets.NumberSelector
        android:id="@+id/ifr_landings_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_ifr_approaches"
        android:visibility="gone"
        custom:orientation="vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ifr_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ifr_landings_selector"
        android:hint="@string/ifr_hours_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cross_country_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ifr_hours"
        android:hint="@string/cross_country_hours_hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_takeoffs_landings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cross_country_hours"
        android:hint="@string/takeoffs_landings_label" />

    <logbook.app.custom.widgets.NumberSelector
        android:id="@+id/landings_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/label_takeoffs_landings"
        custom:orientation="horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_create_log"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/landings_selector"
        android:onClick="createLog"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_create_log" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I stop the `ScrollView` from scrolling to the top every time one of its children's visibilities is changed between `View.GONE` and `View.Visible`?

Comment: What do you mean don't apply visibility now?

Comment: Remove this from your xml file,  android:visibility="gone"

Comment: I've removed all the 'android:visibility="gone"' from the layout file and used the layout file you provided but the same thing happens. Besides, I need certain Views to be hidden initially when the screen loads, that's why I had 'android:visibility="gone"' in the XML file.

Comment: Ok, Now add android:fillViewPort="true" to the scroll view tag

Comment: @user1692855 I am having the same problem. Did you find ant solution?

Comment: if you set fillViewport true your childviews might gets disappeared!

Comment: @faridghar do you find any solution? please help us

Comment: @zihadrizkyef to be honest, this was a very long time ago now (7+ years). I don't remember what my solution was back then.

Comment: Yaps, i am so sorry for this bump
But, FYAI i got the solution. that is put `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in our recyclerView xml.
I got this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56041829/6217595

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to scrolldown you scrollbar at new visible view `crossCountryHoursTextBox` 
for that just scroll your scrollbar like this

```
// scrollview at visible textbox
yourscroll.smoothScrollBy(0,crossCountryHoursTextBox.getTop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation = "vertical" >

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/flight_date"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/aeroplane_type"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/flight_date"
    android:hint="@string/aeroplane_type" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/aeroplane_registration"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/aeroplane_type"
    android:hint="@string/aeroplane_registration" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pilot_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/aeroplane_registration"
    android:hint="@string/pilot_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/copilot_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/pilot_name"
    android:hint="@string/copilot_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/from_aerodome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/copilot_name"
    android:hint="@string/from_aerodome" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/to_aerodome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/copilot_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/from_aerodome"
    android:hint="@string/to_aerodome" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/remarks"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/from_aerodome"
    android:hint="@string/remarks" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/aircraft_engine_type_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/remarks" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/time_of_day_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/aircraft_engine_type_spinner" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/pilot_role_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_of_day_spinner" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/on_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/pilot_role_spinner"
    android:hint="@string/on_time_hint" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/takeoff_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/on_time"
    android:hint="@string/takeoff_time_hint" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/landing_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/takeoff_time"
    android:hint="@string/landing_time_hint" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/off_time"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/landing_time"
    android:hint="@string/off_time_hint" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_record"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/off_time"
    android:onClick="recordTime"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/button_record" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_reset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/off_time"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_record"
    android:onClick="resetAllTimes"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/button_reset" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_ifr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_record"
    android:text="@string/checkbox_ifr"
    android:onClick="ifrCheckboxClicked" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_cross_country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_record"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkbox_ifr"
    android:text="@string/checkbox_cross_country"
    android:onClick="crossCountryCheckboxClicked" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/ifr_type_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/checkbox_ifr"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_ifr_approaches"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ifr_type_spinner"
    android:hint="@string/ifr_landings_label"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<logbook.app.custom.widgets.NumberSelector
    android:id="@+id/ifr_landings_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label_ifr_approaches"
    android:visibility="gone"
    custom:orientation="vertical" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ifr_hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ifr_landings_selector"
    android:hint="@string/ifr_hours_hint"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cross_country_hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/ifr_hours"
    android:hint="@string/cross_country_hours_hint"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_takeoffs_landings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/cross_country_hours"
    android:hint="@string/takeoffs_landings_label" />

<logbook.app.custom.widgets.NumberSelector
    android:id="@+id/landings_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/label_takeoffs_landings"
    custom:orientation="horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_create_log"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/landings_selector"
    android:onClick="createLog"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/button_create_log" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This didn't help. The same behaviour still persists.

Comment: Now add android:fillViewPort="true" to the scroll view tag

Comment: Still no progress. Just to be clear, I've added `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView` element. I've removed all `android:visibility="gone"` from the layout file. I've changed`android:layout_height="fill_parent" to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Check my answer, you can see changes

Comment: I copied and pasted your current answer exactly as is. I ignored a warning I was receiving that said "This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless" and there is still no change. Do you have a suspicion what the problem is or are you trying the trial and error approach?

Comment: Yesterday i got the same problem you faced, but i rectified it.At present i'm in home and after going to office i will rectify your problem. You try it with LinearLayout with vertical orientation

Comment: I didn't try it with a LinearLayout because this screen requires certain Views to be next to eachother horizontally, and from what I know, this cannot be done using a LinearLayout. I'll fallback to using a LinearLayout if I have to, but I'm not convinced that there's no solution to this problem. I can't be the only person who has ever tried to hide a View within a ScrollView! I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: please try it may help you, Surely i will find solution for you and reply to this post itself

Comment: I just tried it with LinearLayout and a vertical orientation and it works! As I said before, I'd like to get it working with a RelativeLayout, so I'll be waiting for your solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  However, changing my RelativeLayout to LinearLayout did not help.  Can you elaborate on the workaround?

Comment: I just got it to work by changing RelativeLayout to LinearLayout.  Can anyone explain why RelativeLayout has this behavior, and how to make it work without switching to LinearLayout?  Thanks.

Comment: Relative layout is good for your android programming, when your going to use in this way