# how to prevent recyclerview auto scroll to bottom when insert new items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` to view my data, but when there are many items ,`RecyclerView` will auto scroll to the bottom everytime a new item is inserted. how to prevent it ?

this is the insert code:

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    getOneMessage(dataSnapshot.getKey(), new OneMessageCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void OnCallBack(Object_Message message) {

            Object_Conversation conversation=new Object_Conversation(dataSnapshot.getKey(),message);

            mConvers_List.add(conversation);
            mConvers_Adapter.notifyItemInserted(mConvers_List.size()-1); 
        }
    });
}
```

this the the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_conversations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="@color/white">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you meant ?

Comment: can you provide your log of `mConvers_List.size()-1` ?

Comment: you meant Logcat ? sorry, I am a newbie

Comment: yes just use Logcat and tell me log

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in recyclerview. This will help you avoid autoscroll

Comment: it works,  but if I sort when add item, It does not

Comment: If i use notifyitemmove (sort) while insert ,the list will scroll

Comment: This ain't working. Not the exact solution. Rather than this, one can use scrollToPosition(0),

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to disable the autoscroll you need to use `notifyItemRangeInserted` instead of `notifyItemInserted`. This should not make your RV scroll to the bottom.

```
final int positionStart = mConvers_List.size() + 1;
mConvers_List.add(conversation);
notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, mConvers_List.size());
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use scrollToPosition(int position)  method to scroll back to zero position.

```
RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
```

Comment: I just want it "stay" for the first time. after that it does not have to "stay" any more